# iPhone - Make loadView entries fill up parent view?

Tags: iphone, layout, uiview, loadview

I have a loadView call that basically places one view at the top (like a header) and one at the bottom (like a footer). It's possible via a passed in parameter to not have a header or a footer, to hide them later, or to resize the view. I have all this working, but it's very susceptible to breaking because the views can go in various places of various sizes and all must be manually set to the correct size or they will not use up all the space. I want one in between the two of them that automatically resizes to fill whatever space is not taken by the others.

loadView doesn't seem to be able to obtain the size of its parent's frame (or where it's being fit in, exactly), nor do I see an obvious way to just put the center view at a certain position and have its width and height automatically adapted.

Any ideas?

If I'm not explaining myself well enough and you know Java Swing, think BorderLayout with a BorderLayout.NORTH, BorderLayout.SOUTH, and BorderLayout.CENTER component.

Answer (score 0):

loadView isn't a good place for this.  You really want to use viewWillAppear instead.  Setting autoresizeMask to have fixed borders should do what you want without having to worry about calculating layout, and it's best to do this all in IB rather than doing manual layout all the time.

Comment: I use IB most of the time, but this is meant to be a standard UI element type so it can't load from a NIB.